Origin of the idea that cranes ballast themselves for flight, in Drayton’s ‘The Owl’
In his poem ‘The Owl’, Michael Drayton lists some lessons taught by various species of bird:

And every bird shew’d in his proper kind,
What virtue nature had to him assign’d
Michael Drayton (1604). ‘The Owl’. In Works (1753), volume 4, p. 1291. London: W. Reeve.

Thus the turtledove teaches “chaste nuptial love”, the nightingale “sweet musick”, and so on. But when it comes to the crane:

The Crane to labour, fearing some rough flaw,
With sand and gravel burthening his craw:
Noted by man, which by the same did find
To ballast ships for steddiness in wind.

Many species of bird swallow small stones and keep them in their gizzards to assist with the maceration of food. But the idea that cranes do so to ballast themselves for steadiness in flight is pure fancy. Where did Drayton get this idea from?

This idea goes way back, at least as far as the ancient Greeks.

Among birds, as it was previously remarked, the crane migrates from one extremity of the earth to the other, and they fly against the wind. As for the story about the stone, it is a fiction, for they say that they carry a stone as ballast, which is useful as a touchstone for gold, after they have vomited it up.
-- Aristotle, History of Animals (Cresswell translation), c. 350 BCE


It is certain that when [cranes] are going to fly across the Black Sea they first of all make for the straits between the two promontories of Ramsbrow and Carambis, and proceed to ballast themselves with sand; and that when they have crossed the middle of the sea they throw away the pebbles out of their claws and, when they have reached the mainland, the sand out of their throats as well.
-- Pliny the Elder, Natural History (Eichholz translation), 77-79 CE


When cranes are about to leave their Thracian haunts and the frosts of Thrace, they collect on the river Hebrus, and when each one has swallowed a stone by way of food and as ballast against the onslaught of winds, they prepare to emigrate and to set out for the Nile, longing for the warmth and for the food that is to be had there during the winter.
-- Aelianus, On the Nature of Animals (Scholfield translation), c. 200 CE


It is indeed obvious that in winter cranes congregate in great numbers in this northern region. It will not grieve me to recall how they direct their journeys. They go forward like a military company under a standard. Lest the strength of the breeze blow them off course, they consume sand, and ballast themselves with small stones to a moderate weight.
-- Solinus, Polyhistor (Arwen Apps translation), 3rd century CE

These and other sources can be seen gathered together here. Even just the oldest two included references to cranes using sand/stones as ballast, Aristotle and Pliny, are two such well-known sources that, even if it's impossible to trace an exact path from Michael Drayton to one of them, it's very reasonable to suppose that the idea had made its way, either directly or indirectly, from them to Drayton.
